# get count of lines while in pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, sort, tee

i have a bash script that looks like this:

```
some_process | sort -u | other_process >> some_file
```

I'd like to get the line count to while i'm streaming the data, after the data is sorted but before it's processed by other_process, i tried something like this:

```
some_process | sort -u | tee >(wc -l > $some_var_i_can_print_later) | other_process >> some_file
```

This didn't work for me, is there any way to achieve storing the count in a variable while streaming data in pipes?

Also, i'd like to avoid using tmpfiles that i need to worry about cleaning up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiddling with file descriptors might get you some further:

```
VAR=$(
  exec 3>&1
  some_process | sort -u | tee >(wc -l >&3) | other_process >> some_file
)
```

Or:

```
VAR=$({
  some_process | sort -u | tee >(wc -l >&3) | other_process >> some_file
} 3>&1)
```

`other_process`'s output is appended to `some_file`, but `wc -l`'s is redirected to fd `3`, which in turn points to the original stdout to be assigned to VAR.